# How to script out testing local user login success/fail in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there a powershell command / script out there that would allow me to step through a list of VMs in a subscription (hundreds) and test whether or not a given local admin user is able to login to Windows? I'd like to tie in and log a response code on this logic for audit purposes but I can't find a Powershell command that tests logins to Windows...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service

Comment: that's a nice way to start you SO career.